# undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I getting a nil class error. I understand exactly what this error is telling me but I don't know why it's nil. It seems to me that there should be an object getting passed to my table. This should be easy to debug. Here is my code for clarity.

CONTROLLER METHOD:

```
def info
  @subscriber = Subscriber.find_by_phone_number(params[:phone_number])
end
```

VIEW:

```
 <% @subscriber.each do |subscriber| %>
  <tr>
   <td><%= image_tag avatar_url(subscriber) %></td>
  </tr>
 <% end %>
```

ERROR:

```
 Showing /Users/intern/Desktop/Rails/rowster/app/views/subscribers/info.html.erb where line #3 raised:
 undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

Binding on info method:

```
[1] pry(#<SubscribersController>)> @subscriber
 => nil
```

let me know if you need anymore info?

Comment: Did you run `info` before the code here? Otherwise `@subscriber` would not be initialized.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "run `info`"? I a bit new to all this so I miss silly things still

Comment: can you add two debugs on your info method? below the existent line, logger.debug @subscriber and logger.debug params. Edit with the output

Comment: This error means that @subscriber is nil.  What Cary was asking is if your info action is run prior to the view being rendered.  If it is being run then the problem is that you have no subscribers with the phone number being passed in.  If it is not being run then that is your problem.

Comment: In your `info` method, can you place a `binding.pry` to confirm the value of  `@subscriber`?

Comment: It's nil when I run pry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two issues here:

First: `@subscriber.each` fails with `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass`. This basically tells you that you try to call `each` in something that is `nil`, therefore `@subscriber` must be `nil`. That means `Subscriber.find_by_phone_number(params[:phone_number])` didn't return a subscriber. The phone number send to the server doesn't have a matching entry in the database.

Second: Even if there were a matching entry in the database, your code would fail. Because `find_by_phone_number` would return *one* subscriber and not an array. Therefore calling `each` would fail again.

To solve both issues change your code to:

```
<% if @subscriber %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= image_tag avatar_url(@subscriber) %></td>
  </tr>
<% else %>
  <tr><td>No subscriber found!</td></tr>
<% end %>
```

And use a phone number that is in the database.

Comment: Adjust the `if` with <% else %>.